# In Drupal 8 view.html.twig file how do I access the view content such as individual field title and/or field content?

Tags: views, theming, 8

Using `views-view.html.twig` as a starting point, I can output `{{ rows }}`, but I want to loop through each field of each row to aggregate and style them.

In Drupal 7, I use `dpm(rows)` to locate (in the array) where content, label etc. But `kint` doesn't seem to provide me the same information. Can anyone help?

Comment: OK, so I've discovered the template preprocess function for my view, but I'm still unsure how to output specific variables...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In views-view.html.twig is not appropriate to style your row and fields.

To style them first you need override template "views_view_'format_style'" (format style specified when you edit/create a view). Here you can style row and access 'fields' variables (use kint(row) to see them).

Something like:

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  {{ kint(row) }} {# devel #}
  <h2> {{row.content['#node'].getTitle()}} </h2> {# access fields #}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

For style fields its better override field template.

For example `field--node--body--article.html.twig`:

```
{% set mode = element['#view_mode'] %}
{% if label_hidden %}
  {% for item in items %}
    {% if mode == 'full' %}
        <div{{ attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% elseif mode == 'teaser' %}
        <p{{ attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <div{{ attributes }}>
    <div{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</div>
    {% for item in items %}
      <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```