# twig for loop access value using array

Tags: views, theming, 8

i have a for loop

```
{% for row in rows %}
    {{ row.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

will print out like this

```
<div> one </div>
<div> two </div>
<div> three </div>
<div> ... </div>
```

but what i want to is access the values using a key so i can pull the values individually so i can do some thing like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div> one </div>
</div>

<div class="second-container">
    <div> one </div>
</div>

<div class="anyclassname">
    <div> one </div>
</div>
```

basically print the value anywhere i want on a div of my choice. Is it possible ?? please help

this is for a views template

Comment: Is this for a node template or a view template?

Comment: it is for views template --- it would be great if you can suggest a good book on twig with in-depth explanations and examples... i checked out the the symphony2 site the documentation is too short.. also seems like twig does not support switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In views-view.html.twig is not appropriate to style your row and fields.

To style them first you need override template "views_view_'format_style'" (format style specified when you edit/create a view). Here you can style row and access 'fields' variables (use kint(row) to see them).

Something like:

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {%
    set row_classes = [
      default_row_class ? 'views-row',
    ]
  %}
  {{ kint(row) }} {# devel #}
  <h2> {{row.content['#node'].getTitle()}} </h2> {# access fields #}
  <div{{ row.attributes.addClass(row_classes) }}>
    {{ row.content }}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

For style fields its better override field template.

For example field--node--body--article.html.twig:

```
{% set mode = element['#view_mode'] %}
{% if label_hidden %}
  {% for item in items %}
    {% if mode == 'full' %}
        <div{{ attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% elseif mode == 'teaser' %}
        <p{{ attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</p>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <div{{ attributes }}>
    <div{{ title_attributes }}>{{ label }}</div>
    {% for item in items %}
      <div{{ item.attributes }}>{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}
```

source : [In Drupal 8 view.html.twig file how do I access the view content such as individual field title and/or field content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187615/in-drupal-8-view-html-twig-file-how-do-i-access-the-view-content-such-as-individ)

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html

Answer (score 1):

The fastest/easiest solution is to click on the field, then click on **Re-Write Results**

Use the replacement pattern for your field, and put something like this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div> {{ field_name }} </div>
</div>

<div class="second-container">
    <div> {{ field_name }} </div>
</div>

<div class="anyclassname">
    <div> {{ field_name }} </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could create a **views-view-fields--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg).html.twig** file and put the same code there.

---

If your field in question, has unlimited values:

- Click in your field and under **Multiple field settings**, *uncheck* the `Display all values in the same row` box.

[image]

---

> its a views page with three fields... // 2 image and a text -- all of this needs to me printed on the same div..

Then in your template file put:

```
<div class="container">
{{ fields.field_company_color_scheme.content }}
{{ fields.field_port_landing_feature.content }}
{{ fields.field_com.content }}
</div>
```

Comment: lets say the for loop has 7 element in it --- say "One" "two" "three" and so on... now if i were to called the field_name seven times how will the iteration work... will it cycle on its own and print the next content ? I can call the field_name had been for something like node/page for a content...

Comment: @TheNagaTanker, There is no need to for loop with my answer. Think of it as rows, `one` would be row 1, `two` would be row 2, etc...

Comment: its a views page with three fields... // 2 image and a text -- all of this needs to me printed on the same div..

Comment: @TheNagaTanker see updated answer.

Comment: these are the fields   

field_company_color_scheme
field_port_landing_feature
field_com

Comment: Use the code given in the "Replacement Patterns"

Comment: sorry for keeping the questions coming -- appreciate your help...

i made the views page as html--portfolio-landing-views.html.twig

    <div class="container">
    {{ field_company_color_scheme }}
    {{ field_port_landing_feature }}
    {{ field_com }}
     </div>

nothing is being displayed

Comment: @TheNagaTanker you need to name it as I mentioned in my original answer `views-view-fields--[view-name]--[machine-name].html.twig` and clear/flush the cache to see changes.

Comment: thank you so much... however its still not working have done exactly as you've said...

Comment: @TheNagaTanker lets assume [this is your machine name](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vsMjX.jpg) and your view name is "Hello World". Then your template name should be `views-view-fields--hello-world--block-1.html.twig` This template file needs to be inside your current theme's template folder. **Note:** The view preview will not show the changes since it uses the `Seven (admin) theme`. Unless you put the file in Seven's theme template folder, it will not show/reflect in the preview.

Comment: thank you for your valuable time you have spent to help me..
I did exactly as you said....

views-view-fields--portfolio-viadesign--page-1.html.twig is the template i created as you said. Also added a random text with the fields div... I do see that for every div section there are three iterations printing the text 3 time... however the pictures and the text associated with the fields do show up. By the way this is a views page.

Comment: @TheNagaTanker updated my answer, since you are using the template way, then you need to print them like this `{{ fields.field_name.content }}`

Comment: ive tried that too...nothing is printed out

Comment: thanks for the reply ... however each field is being iterated  twice so {{ fields.field_name.content }} will display two content in its index ( lets assume [0] [1]... if i add the second {{ fields.field_name.content }} statement it does not move to the next index [2] [3] but prints the content of [0] [1]

Comment: can we do something like this {{ products.0 }} / {{ products[0] }} / {{ products[random(5)] }}

Answer (score 0):

SO this is what i've come up with

so instead of using

```
{% for row in rows %}
    {{ row.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

what i did was completely remove the for loop and used this instead

```
<div class= red > {{ rows[0] . content}} </div>
<div class= yellow > {{ rows[1] . content}} </div>
<div class= blue > {{ rows[2] . content}} </div>
<div class= green > {{ rows[3] . content}} </div>
```

this way i can also control how many items are displayed and give a div name of your choice or within another div.

now the question remains on how to take apart the

```
  {{ rows[0] . content}}
```

the array within the {{ content }} part so they can be further broken apart... any Idea ???