# Access fields in views-view Twig template

Tags: views, theming, 8

I'm trying to loop through `rows` in a `views-view` template, but I can't seem to `kint` or `dump` anything out to help me in doing so.

I've tried following various other answers, such as:

- [In Drupal 8 view.html.twig file how do I access the view content such as individual field title and/or field content?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187615/in-drupal-8-view-html-twig-file-how-do-i-access-the-view-content-such-as-individ)
- [How to get each field value in views-views-unformatted--view-machine-name.html.twig?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208201/how-to-get-each-field-value-in-views-views-unformatted-view-machine-name-html-t)

Again, without any success.

Usually I'd create a `views-view-fields` template, and access my fields via `fields.title.content` for example. I need to loop through them via the `views-view` template, as I'm needing to do some checks, taking into account values of some of the previous row's fields.

**How can I access a rows fields when looping through `rows` in my `views-view` template?**

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should be using views-view-fields.html.twig instead of views-view-unformatted.html.twig file.

Views fields template will iterate on all rows of result. Your views-view-fields.html.twig should contain below code -

```
<div>
  <a class="view-row" href="{{variable-to-print-path }}">
   <img src="{{ image-path }}">
   <h3>{{ fields.title.content</h3>
  </a>
</div>
```

You can check the fields array by using kint function like - {{ kint(fields) }}

Check for image path and anchor path variable from output of kint function.

If you want to do this in views-view-unformatted.html.twig, then you can access the field values like below -

```
{% for row in rows %}
  {% set photo = file_url(row['content']['#row']._entity.field_page_photo.entity.fileuri) %}          
  <li><img src={{ photo }} class="img-responsive img-circle"></li>
{% endfor %}
```